# Getting HTTP Error 500 with SPARQL query to DBPedia endpoint using Python's SPARQLwrapper

Tags: python, sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to receive all properties whose labels contain a certain string. I use the following query:

```
    SELECT ?p ?l count(?p) as ?count WHERE { 
    ?someobj ?p ?s .
    ?p a <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property> .        
    ?p <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?l . 
    ?l bif:contains "string" . 
    FILTER (lang(?l) = 'en'). 
    FILTER (!isLiteral(?someobj)). 
    } ORDER BY DESC(?count) LIMIT 5
```

When issueing the query through the public DBPedia endpoint @ http://dbpedia.org/sparql, it works, and returns what I want. However when I do the same through the SPARQLWrapper in my Python script, I keep getting:

```
File "E:\thesis\sem_web21.py", line 254, in findWord
  results = sparql.query().convert()
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py", line 355, in query
  return QueryResult(self._query())
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py", line 334, in _query
  raise e
HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: SPARQL Request Failed
```

I have tried variations on the query, with and without counting and sorting, with and without limiting. I keep getting HTTP 500s. I don't think it's the endpoint being instable, as I have no problem with other queries in the same script, it only stops with this query.

Similar queries to retrieve objects work fine (both at the public endpoint as through my script):

```
    SELECT ?s ?l count(?s) as ?count WHERE { 
    ?someobj ?p ?s . 
    ?s <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?l . 
    ?l bif:contains "computer" . 
    FILTER (!regex(str(?s), '^http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:')). 
    FILTER (!regex(str(?s), '^http://dbpedia.org/resource/List')). 
    FILTER (!regex(str(?s), '^http://sw.opencyc.org/')). 
    FILTER (lang(?l) = 'en'). 
    FILTER (!isLiteral(?someobj)). 
    } ORDER BY DESC(?count) LIMIT 20
```

Any idea what could be causing this? Or any idea how I could retrieve a more specific error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a time out error on dbpedia's part because it looks it up in different graphs. When you are trying it through the dbpedia web interface it always includes the uri of the graph you are querying. So try adding that to your query:

```
SELECT ?p ?l count(?p) as ?count FROM <http://dbpedia.org> WHERE { 
?someobj ?p ?s .
?p a <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property> .        
?p <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?l . 
?l bif:contains "string" . 
FILTER (lang(?l) = 'en'). 
FILTER (!isLiteral(?someobj)). 
} ORDER BY DESC(?count) LIMIT 5
```

and try it again.

Tried it using the following python script:

```
import sys
import urllib,urllib2

def query_e(query,epr,soft_limit=True):
   try:
       params = urllib.urlencode({'query': query})
       opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
       request = urllib2.Request(epr+'?'+params)
       request.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')
       request.get_method = lambda: 'GET'
       url = opener.open(request)
       data = url.read()
       return data
    except Exception, e:
       traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
       raise e
```

Answer (score 1):

The COUNT expression should be `(count(?p) as ?count)`, with the brackets.

Not sure that's the problem here, but thought I should point it out.